# Show employees who earn more

Tags: sql

I want to get a cursor which shows me the 3 employees who earn more. Here is the table, SOU means salary.

```
Nombre                                    ┐Nulo?   Tipo
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 CODI_EMPL                                 NOT NULL NUMBER(3)
 NOM_EMPL                                  NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20)
 COGNOM_EMPL                               NOT NULL VARCHAR2(50)
 SOU                                       NOT NULL NUMBER(8,2)
 NOM_DPT                                            VARCHAR2(20)
 CIUTAT_DPT                                         VARCHAR2(20)
 CODI_PROJ                                          NUMBER(3)
```

So I want to create a procedure which stores the three employees who earn more, obviously with CURSOR. I do not know here to start, i do not know who the query should be... Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you're trying to find the three employees who earn the most? Like an `ORDER BY SOU DESC LIMIT 3`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think you need cursor for this. Try this query

```
SELECT  * FROM 
(
SELECT * FROM Table
ORDER BY SOU desc
)
WHERE rownum <= 3
ORDER BY SOU;
```